# Big O Notation of the terms f(n) = 2^(n+5) + n^2 and g(n) = 2^(n+1) - 1

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I have:

- () = 2<sup>+5</sup> + <sup>2</sup>
- () = 2<sup>+1</sup> - 1

I must show whether:

- ()  = Ω(()) or/and
- ()  = O(())

I know that you don't need to acknowledge the <sup>2</sup> in () or the -1 in () because 2<sup>+5</sup> and 2<sup>+1</sup> have the higher complexity. But I'm not really sure how to find out the lower and the upper bound.

My approach would be to say that the +5 in () and the +1 in () doesn't change anything about the complexity, which means that both of the above statements are true and () = θ​(()). But I have no way to prove this.

Comment: Please shorten your title. Titles are Titles. Keep them short and Googlable :)

Comment: Use parentheses to clearly indicate what is part of the exponent and what not.

Comment: @trincot I just edited the post. I wasn't able to add the terms as images but I added them as code.

Comment: Just do it like trincot said, including in the title. (Btw did you misspell Zora's Name?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

- () = 2<sup>+5</sup> + <sup>2</sup>
- () = 2<sup>+1</sup> − 1

() = Ω(()) is true when we can find a  such that () ≥ ⋅()) for any  greater than a chosen <sub><sub>0</sub></sub>.

We see that even with =1 and <sub><sub>0</sub></sub>=0 this is true.

() = O(()) is true when we can find a  such that () ≤ ⋅()) for any  greater than a chosen <sub><sub>0</sub></sub>:

2<sup>+5</sup> + <sup>2</sup> ≤ (2<sup>+1</sup> − 1)

Let's choose  = 2<sup>5</sup>, then we must show that for large enough :

2<sup>+5</sup> + <sup>2</sup> ≤ 2<sup>5</sup>(2<sup>+1</sup> − 1)

2<sup>+5</sup> + <sup>2</sup> ≤ 2⋅2<sup>+5</sup> − 32

<sup>2</sup> ≤ 2<sup>+5</sup> − 32

We can see that this is true for all  greater than 1.

Comment: The definition I know also allows for a finite beginning segment of values of n to invalidate the property. It usually goes along the lines "there exists a non-negative n0 s.t. for all n >= n0 ... [the inequality holds]".

Comment: Yes, which is what I expressed as *"for any  greater than a chosen ₀"*, which I agree is a bit fluffy, but the more mathematical standard way of formulating it can become a hard-to-read phrase.